# Pandas get row correspondences

Tags: pandas

Using pandas, how can I find the position of rows of one dataframe in another dataframe?

Example:

We have a dataframe df_A

```
import pandas as pd
df_A = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2,3], [1, 3,4], [1, 4,9]], columns=['idx_1', 'idx_2','values'])
```

and another dataframe df_B

```
df_B = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 4]], columns=['idx_1', 'idx_2'])
```

I want to the correspondence between the idx-columns of df_A to the idx-columns of df_B:

```
     idx_1  idx_2  values row_B
0      1      2      3     0
1      1      3      4     NAN
2      1      4      9     1
```

Comment: You can perform a join on those 2 columns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and `rename` for avoid losing index of `df_B`:

```
df2 = df_B.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'row_B'})
df = df_A.merge(df2, how='left', on=['idx_1', 'idx_2'])
print (df)
   idx_1  idx_2  values  row_B
0      1      2       3    0.0
1      1      3       4    NaN
2      1      4       9    1.0
```